# When popping from a child view back to a parent view shouldn't the parent send viewWillAppear?

Tags: ios6, uinavigationitem, viewwillappear

I have a UITableView as a root.
I have a UIView as a parent with the object data from one row of the table.

I have a UIView as a child with a UITextView that will update one attribute of the object.

In the parent view:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.priorityDurationControl setTitle:self.thisTask.hours.description forSegmentAtIndex:2];}
```

In the child view:

```
- (IBAction)durationChanged:(UITextField *)sender {
    self.thisTask.hours = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[sender.text doubleValue]];
    NSError *saveError = nil;
    [[self.thisTask managedObjectContext] save:&saveError];
}
```

When I use the navigation item to pop back to the parent view, the UISegmentedControl is not updated. However, if I pop back to the root table view and then select the row to go back to that parent view the UISegmentedControl **is** updated.

When popping from a child view back to a parent view shouldn't the parent send viewWillAppear?

Comment: I've tried -(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.priorityDurationControl setTitle:self.thisTask.hours.description forSegmentAtIndex:2];
} with no luck.

Comment: Perhaps set a breakpoint or use NSLog to check if `viewWillAppear` is called or not. - Is `self.thisTask` the same object in parent and child view controller?

Comment: Thanks, Martin. A liberal sprinkling of NSLog statements tracked down the problem. First, viewWillAppear WAS and is firing. The problem was outside the scope of the code in my first question. The text field was attached to - (IBAction)durationChanged:(UITextField *)sender through Editing Did End. However the text field is set to UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad, so there's no return key. Editing Did End doesn't get called in this view until the view is popped and viewWillAppear on the parent view is called BEFORE the Editing Did End is called as the child view is popped.

Comment: Short answer, I need to update self.thisTask.hours in viewWillDisappear in the child view, or update the segmented controller in viewDidAppear.